# Is there an excel function similar to CASE? If not, how would I solve

Tags: excel, function, case, vlookup

I'm trying to figure out what function to use to help me solve my dilemma. The basics of it are this:

I need to bring in a "Category Number" into my excel sheet. This "Category Number" is dependent upon two things.

1. Billing Code
2. and something called CPM.

A billing code can have multiple category numbers depending on what range a CPM falls into. For example:

Billing code 4 has the following category numbers: 37, 80, 85.

`IF CPM for this company is > 5000 use category number 37`
`IF CPM for this company is > 10000 use category number 80`
`IF CPM for this company is > 20000 use category number 85.`

This is a very rudimentary example, but currently I'm using a VLOOKUP to bring in ALL of the associated category numbers.

That is, I'll have

`Company ||    Billing Code    ||  Category Number   ||   CPM`

`ABC     ||       4           ||       37,80,85    ||         5250`

my VLOOKUP is what bring in '37,80,85' but what I really need it to do is first look at the billing code, determine the corresponding category numbers, and then narrow this down to just 1 category number depending on the CPM.

Is this still feasible by using a VLOOKUP? do I have to construct my table array differently? Any thoughts on how to approach it. It seems as though if I had a CASE function it'd make my life easier ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(BillingCode<5000,"BillingCode too low",LOOKUP(BillingCode,{5000,10000,20000},{37,80,85}))
```

Where BillingCode is a cell reference to the cell containing the Billing Code.
For example, if it should reference cell B2, then:

```
=IF(B2<5000,"BillingCode too low",LOOKUP(B2,{5000,10000,20000},{37,80,85}))
```

Answer (score 0):

A CASE structure is really just a bunch of **else if** statements chained together. You can certainly replicate that with the IF() function in excel. I think it can only go seven IF() statements deep though.

```
=IF(AND(A4>5000,A4<=10000),"37",IF(AND(A4>10000,A4<=20000),"80",IF(A4>20000,"A4","")))
```

Although I have a feeling there is a better way to solve your problem. Maybe with some kind of within-range-vlookup kind of system. That way you can have more than seven ranges to check for.

**EDIT/ADDITION**

Yea so it looks like that functionality is already built into VLOOKUP(). You can have separate tables with your top limits and their corresponding Category # - i.e.:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$4,2,TRUE),"")
```

Example:

[image: Example1]